# Setting up an SMTP server to work in conjunction with an AJAX/PHP contact form

Tags: php, email, smtp, server

I'm currently having issues creating a contact form on my website.

I'm wanting to utilize a contact form on my website that uses a local email server (postfix) to send the mail.

Currently I'm having issues implementing this functionality. Is an SMTP server required to send a filled out contact form to a specific email address?

Example...

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "email_goes_here"; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$headers = "From:" . $email;
mail($to,$email,$name,$message);
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

}
?>
```

Would I need an SMTP server to successfully send this captured data to an email address? (captured data being the data put into the form, stored using the POST method).

If I'm on the right track so far, can anyone point me in the right direction to configuring an SMTP server to work with PHP??

This contact form has been an absolute night mare

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You need a properly configured STMP server to send emails, yes. This server of yours, is an own server or your website is hosted elsewhere?

Comment: This server is my own server and I currently use post fix as the email server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your eMail server is working well and therefore you can receive and send emails with it, the only configuration needed for php to be able to send emails within the localhost is in its php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

The 3 first lines might be already in your standard config, being the 4th one the relevant for you.

Save the file after you modify it and restart the Apache server.

Check that your new configuration is working by typing the following command in a terminal window:

```
echo testing | mail -s Test email@domain.com
```

Regards

**EDIT:**

More information about the sendmail command for postfix:

http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html

Comment: I went into php.ini and changed those params but still nothing. Surely I'm not missing something

Comment: What's the output of "echo testing | mail -s Test email@domain.com"?

Comment: That terminal command has done nothing, just creates a new line.

Comment: I can telnet the server, routing just doesn't seem to be working. Emails sent out don't work.

Comment: Use again the terminal command and look afterwards at the postfix logs to detect any related problems. Log files should be found at /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Fixed it. It was working perfectly fine, my ajax function was referencing the wrong ID -.-

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! :-)